# Is there anyway I can store the static std::vectors of pointers of all my derived classes in my base class?

Tags: object-oriented, c++, inheritance, array

I currently have a program that has multiple derived classes. All instances of a derived class are stored inside of that class's static vector of pointers. I also have a static vector of pointers which is inside of the base class which stores any object that has been derived from it. Whenever I add an object I currently have two push backs, one for the derived class and one for the base class. This means I also have to do two deletions when I want to get rid of an object. Is there anyway I can store the static vectors of pointers of all my derived classes in my base class? I keep thinking about using a 2d vector in my base class, would that work?

```
class Derived_class : public Base_class
{
     static std::vector<Derived_class *> Lamps
}

class Derived_class2 : public Base_class
{
     static std::vector<Derived_class2 *> Tables
}

class Base_class
{
     static std::vector<Base_class *> Furniture
}
```

Sorry in advance for any faux pas or if I'm not giving enough information.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep an associative container in the base, mapping something representing the derived type to a list of instances.

The `typeid` operator returns a `std::type_info` reference, which by itself isn't usable as a key. `std::type_index` can be constructed from a `std::type_info` and is suitable as a key in a container.

Your code would then look something like this:

```
std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::vector<Base_class*>> instances;
instances[std::type_index(typeid(*this))].push_back(this);
```

As a side note, you may want to evaluate if a vector is a suitable structure or if you want something with cheaper lookup/erase.

Comment: If that code to register instances is in the constructor of `Base_class`, then it is likely that `typeid(*this)` always reports the type `Base_class`. This is because during the execution of a base-class constructor, the object is actually of that type. It becomes an object of the derived type once the derived class' constructor starts to execute.

Comment: Good catch @BartvanIngenSchenau. I had indeed not specified where this would run. Any suggestions on a clean solution, or exercise for the reader?

Comment: If you're dealing with leaf types only, CRTP with Registrator<Derived> maybe?